# Detectar AdBlock no navegador do usuário e mostrar mensagem

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma, pode ser via JS, que detecte que o usuário está usando AdBlock e envie alguma mensagem para o mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem diversas formas de tentar verificar o uso do Adblock, seguem algumas:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    DetectarAdBlockUser();
});

function DetectarAdBlockUser() {
if ($('.ClassDosSeusAds').filter(':visible').length == 0) {
    $('divAvisoAdBlock').show();
} else if ($('.ClassDosSeusAds').filter(':hidden').length > 0) {
    //colocar o que quer fazer caso alguns estejam hidden
} else if ($('.ClassDosSeusAds').height() == 0) {
    //colocar o que quer fazer
}
```

No caso é verificado a existência do atributo hidden, height igual a zero e caso nao esteja visible.

Observe que cada adblock varia na sua forma de execução e novos updates podem levar a formas de evitar esse tipo de detecção